# Two way data binding in pure JS?

Tags: javascript, data-binding

I need to make two way data binding with JAVASCRIPT.
Two elements: input and span with price. When add any symbol to input price should be increased with 5. One symbol +5 to price. 
Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: When you say "add any symbol to input price", do you mean when the user enters a quantity (i.e. amount purchasing x cost)? or the price is multiplied by the amount of characters in the field (i.e. charged per character)?

Comment: How is input -> span a two way data binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```js
let el = document.getElementById('output');
let input = document.getElementById('input');
let price = document.getElementById('price');

function change () {
  el.innerText = input.value;
  let priceAmount = parseInt(price.innerText);
  priceAmount += 5;
  price.innerText = priceAmount;
  
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput="change()" id="input"/>

<br>

<span id="output"></span>

<br>

<span id="price">0</span>
```

It uses the `oninput` DOM event which calls the function change every time which updates the span element every time according to the input of the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use oninput event on input element.
Ex:

```
<input type='text' id='input' oninput='change()'/>
<br/>
<span id='price'></span>

<script>
function change() {
    // Get value from input
  var rawInput = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var value = parseInt(rawInput);
  // Update value for output
  if (isNaN(value)) {
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = 'Please enter valid value';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = value + 5;
  }
}
</script>
```